# Замена чисел с плавающей запятой после определённого текста

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
String Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Response, @"161407,""FUSDBUY"":2.4350,""FUSDSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""").Groups[1].Value;
```

Вместо `2.4350` нужно найти любое число с плавающей запятой. Как только уже не пробовал не работает.

Текст:

```
161407,"FUSDBUY":2.4350,"FUSDSELL":2.5200,
```

Полный код метода парсера валют:

```
private String AlfabankUSDsell()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    String Response = wc.DownloadString("https://infobank.by/kursy-valyut/rogachev/"); ;
    String Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Response, @"161407,""FUSDBUY"":2.4350,""FUSDSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""").Groups[1].Value;
    return Rate;
}
```

Comment: А если я вам скажу, что вы совершенно неверно делаете все, как вы отреагируете на это? Во первых, добавляем к вашей строке кавычки и удаляем то, что вы скопировали лишнее и получаем `{"FUSDBUY":2.4350,"FUSDSELL":2.5200}`, не знакомо вам? Если нет, то это JSON, очень популярный и очень известный формат, который грех разбирать регулярками! Во вторых, указанный вами сайт получает данные при помощи API, например [вот](https://infobank.by/modules/Ajax/CreateCardTable.aspx?Action=crttbl). Короче, сейчас, вы делаете ерунду и двигаетесь совсем не в том направление, одумайтесь, пока не поздно.

Comment: И в правду, зачем тут регулярки?

Comment: Я первую цифру уже спарсил, И вторую можно, но когда на сайте поменяются курсы все сломается:) Поэтому первую цифру хочется подменить переменной.

Я в JSON понятие не имею.

Comment: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` – а эту штуку кто для вас написал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно именно регулярками парсить, 161407 в регулярке это какая-то известная константа, а 2.4350 это число, которое может измениться, то нужно просто поменять код на

```
private String AlfabankUSDsell()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    String Response = wc.DownloadString("https://infobank.by/kursy-valyut/rogachev/"); ;
    String Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Response, @"161407,""FUSDBUY"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FUSDSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""").Groups[2].Value;


    return Rate;
}
```

Т.е. трактовать первое число, как первую группу в регулярке.

Comment: Я люблю конкретную помощь. Она бесценна. Спасибо!

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, если не добавлять `(`скобки`)`, то первое число будет матчится, но не будет в результах