# Xamarin Forms Android приложение на телефоне не конектит с интернетом (а на эмуляторе все ОК)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

[image: На эмуляторе работает. Курсы валют парсятся отлично.]

[image: На телефоне не коннектится вообще ни как:(]

Вот код метода парсера:

```
        private String BelBankRUBsell()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        String Response = wc.DownloadString("https://infobank.by/kursy-valyut/rogachev/"); ;
        String Rate = Regex.Match(Response, @"128783,""FUSDBUY"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FUSDSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FEURBUY"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FEURSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FRUBBUY"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FRUBSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""").Groups[6].Value;
        double rateX = Convert.ToDouble(Rate);
        rateX = rateX * 100;
        Rate = rateX.ToString("0.000");

        return Rate;
    }
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи. Может я где что что то не включил перед сборкой Apk

Comment: Вы уверены, что "Нет связи" это именно отсутствие соединения? Судя по другим вопросам, вы отправляете GET запрос на сервер и может ему что не нравиться (UserAgent например или другой заголовок)?

Comment: Нет. Данные о курсах парсятся через Regex.Match

Comment: Открываем ваш [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1109482/220553) (где я вам говорил, что вы делаете совершенно не то и вы это по сути пропустили мимо ушей (но да ладно)) и видим `wc.DownloadString(...`, а это - получение данных с сервера. Где вы и как устанавливаете "Нет связи" ? Вангую, что у вас есть `try/catch`, который в случае ошибки выводит это сообщение, либо это у вас стандартное сообщение и в случае ошибки вы просто нечего не выводите. Короче, посмотрите ответ сервера и сообщение ошибки!

Comment: да стоит Try catch

Comment: И, что у вас в `Exception`?

Comment: Regex.Match(Response, @"162091,""FUSDBUY"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""FUSDSELL"":([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),""").Groups[2].Value;

Comment: И к чему эта строка?

Comment: А что за Exception?

Comment: `Exception` - класс, который содержит информацию об ошибке. `try/catch` - отлавливает эту ошибку, в блоке `catch (Exception e)` у вас в `e` будет вся информация об ошибке. Выведите например `Message` и смотрите из за чего у вас "Нет связи".

Comment: Вот что выдала ошибка на телефоне
https://photos.app.goo.gl/MDRnhkegP1qWRCbn9

Comment: Говорил же я вам, работайте с JSON как положено, не слушали, получайте) Вам пишет, что "Входная строка имела неверный формат". Ищите что ваша "регулярка" получает и отдает. Да и вообще, проверьте что вам выдает сервер на устройстве, оправдывает ваши ожидания?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду и ошибке, проблема у вас в строке `Convert.ToDouble(Rate);`, значение `Rate` не является допустимым. Там должно быть число, без пробелов, лишних знаков и в правильном, региональном формате (точка, запитая  (где как)).

Comment: Да, именно в при конвертировании ошибка. Уже думаю как исправить.
Я бы с радостью использовал бы JSON но я в нем вообще ни шарю. Но если с этим не получиться, придется использовать ваш совет:)

Comment: Вы же учитесь программированию, так учитесь правильно сразу. Вам я сказал как правильно, вы же наверно могли бы попробовать постичь что-то новое для себя, но уперто делаете то, что умеете. Так вы далеко не продвинетесь, увы. В интернете (включая SO) полно примеров по работе с JSON форматом, можете даже сами задать вопрос и вам с радостью помогут. Сейчас же, вы будто красите асфальт в дождь, рано или поздно это все упадет.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался я как работать с JSON. Это просто супер удобно и просто.